# Faster alternative to slicing and list comprehension to get an attribute of the last N items in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance

I am looking to speed up my code. I've tried recapping my code in the following:

I start by reading certain CSV files from a folder and store the data in a dict:

Everything is part of methods inside classes.

```
# csv_dir: Folder with all the CSV files
# list: List of which CSV files from the above folder to read

data = {}
for s in list:
    data[s] = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(
        os.path.join(csv_dir, '%s.csv' % s),
        header=0, index_col=0, parse_dates=True, date_parser=dateparse,
        names=names
    )
```

Then I reindex and create a generator

```
# comb_index: Combined index made previously in the code
reindexMethod = None

for s in list:
    data[s] = data[s].reindex(index=comb_index, method=reindexMethod)
    data[s] = data[s].iterrows()
```

Then I loop over all entries where I do the following in each iteration:

- Get new observation using `yield`
- Store new observation in list together with all previously yielded observations
- Call a function that:

  - Get last N entries from the above list using `get_latest_data` (defined below together with helpmethod)
  - Calculate stuff

Code definitions:

```
# self (part of the same class as the rest of the code)
# x: which file to retrieve the latest N datapoints from
# N: Number of datapoints to retrieve

def get_latest_data(x, val_type, N=1):
    try:
        data_list = get_latest_entries(x, N)
    except KeyError:
        print("Not available.")
        raise
    else:
        return np.array([getattr(b[1], val_type) for b in data_list])
```

with help method

```
# latest_data: Dict with all previously looped through data for each CSV file 

def get_latest_entries(x, N=1):
    try:
        bars_list = latest_data[x]
    except KeyError:
        print("Not available.")
        raise
    else:
        return bars_list[-N:]
```

My profiler says that the list comprehension is the problem, but I don't know a better alternative.

Comment: are you sure that `np.array` won't accept an iterator? if it does, just remove the square bracket: `np.array(getattr(b[1], val_type) for b in data_list)`. This will prevent materializing this whole list in-memory.

Comment: few notes about your question phrasing - add tags for pandas (and relevant import). It's unclear what is `self.list` and `self.latest_data` (how is it initialized? what type is it? etc.).

Comment: @guyarad I tried using the np.fromiter function, but it is not giving me faster results than the above solution. Also I have added details to the above. Maybe that will explain things better?

Comment: unclear what type is `self. latest_data` or for that matter `bars_list` in `get_latest_entries`. Depending on that type, doing `bars_list[-N:]` could be expensive (it's a copy of that part of the list). You could do things like `itertools.islice` for Python 2 or I think use `slice` for Python 3. 
As a mentioned earlier - you are generating a list in-memory instead of passing an iterator to `np.array`. Remove the square there.

Comment: @guyarad Seems like I forgot some. Should be there now. I have already tried removing the squarebrackets, as mentioned above and then using the np.fromiter() function. Will look at itertools.

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I'm not super familiar with numpy nor pandas. But the things you are doing don't seem very complex. I don't understand why you needed to replace the method you are using with frontier. You can initialize `np.array` with an iterator (simply delete the square brackets). If you want, I'm willing to try running it. Please provide a single [gist](http://gist.github.com) that simulate the problem and that I can execute standalone. Find a way to send me a sample CSV file.